# Replace several words in a text with Python

Tags: python, performance, unicode, processing-efficiency

I use the below code to remove all HTML tags from a file and convert it to a plain text. Moreover, I have to convert XML/HTML characters to ASCII ones. Here, I have 21 lines which read whole the text. It means if I want to convert a huge file, I have to expend a lot of resource to do this.

**Do you have any idea to increase the efficiency of the code and increase its speed while decrease the usage of the resources?**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

# This file contains HTML.
file = open('input-file.html', 'r')
temp = file.read()

# Replace Some XML/HTML characters to ASCII ones.
temp = temp.replace ('&lsquo;',"""'""")
temp = temp.replace ('&rsquo;',"""'""")
temp = temp.replace ('&ldquo;',"""\"""")
temp = temp.replace ('&rdquo;',"""\"""")
temp = temp.replace ('&sbquo;',""",""")
temp = temp.replace ('&prime;',"""'""")
temp = temp.replace ('&Prime;',"""\"""")
temp = temp.replace ('&laquo;',"""«""")
temp = temp.replace ('&raquo;',"""»""")
temp = temp.replace ('&lsaquo;',"""‹""")
temp = temp.replace ('&rsaquo;',"""›""")
temp = temp.replace ('&amp;',"""&""")
temp = temp.replace ('&ndash;',""" – """)
temp = temp.replace ('&mdash;',""" — """)
temp = temp.replace ('&reg;',"""®""")
temp = temp.replace ('&copy;',"""©""")
temp = temp.replace ('&trade;',"""™""")
temp = temp.replace ('&para;',"""¶""")
temp = temp.replace ('&bull;',"""•""")
temp = temp.replace ('&middot;',"""·""")

# Replace HTML tags with an empty string.
result = re.sub("<.*?>", "", temp)
print(result)

# Write the result to a new file.
file = open("output-file.txt", "w")
file.write(result)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of using `sting.tranlate()` or `string.maketran()` is that when I use them I have to assign A char to another one. e.g.

```
print string.maketran("abc","123")
```

But, I need to assign a HTML/XML char like `&lsquo;` to the single quotation (`'`) in ASCII. It means that I have to use the following code:

```
print string.maketran("&lsquo;","'")
```

It faces the following error:

> ValueError: maketrans arguments must have same length

Whereas, if I use HTMLParser, it will convert all HTML/XML to ASCII without the above problem. I also have added a `encode('utf-8')` to solve the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in
>   position 246: ordinal not in range(128)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# This file contains HTML.
file = open('input-file.txt', 'r')
temp = file.read()

# Replace all XML/HTML characters to ASCII ones.
temp = HTMLParser.unescape.__func__(HTMLParser, temp)

# Replace HTML tags with an empty string.
result = re.sub("<.*?>", "", temp)

# Encode the text to UTF-8 for preventing some errors.
result = result.encode('utf-8')
print(result)

# Write the result to a new file.
file = open("output-file.txt", "w")
file.write(result)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use string.translate()

```
from string import maketrans   # Required to call maketrans function.

intab = "string of original characters that need to be replaced"
outtab = "string of new characters"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)# maketrans() is helper function in the string module to create a translation table

str = "this is string example....wow!!!";#you string
print str.translate(trantab);
```

Note that in python3 str.translate will be significantly slower than in python2, especially if you translate only few characters. This is because it must handle unicode characters and thus uses a dict to perform the translations instead of indexing a string.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is [`string.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) in combination with [`string.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) This will make only one pass instead of several. Each call to [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does its own pass of the entire string and you want to avoid that.

An example:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, maketrans, translate

from_str = ascii_lowercase
to_str = from_str[-1]+from_str[0:-1]
foo = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
bar = translate(foo, maketrans(from_str, to_str))
print bar # sgd pthbj aqnvm enw itlor nudq sgd kzyx cnf.
```